# Elasticsearch: how to call mustNot the same length as the array Java High Level REST Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kotlin

How do I make a query like this?

**REST API Query**

```js
{ "query": { "must_not": [ {"match": {"foreignId": 1}}, {"match": {"foreignId": 2}}, ...  ] }
```

**Kotlin code**

```
fun searchWithExclude(foreignIdsForMustNot: List<Int>) {
    val q = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("id", foreignIdsForMustNot[0]))
        .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("id", foreignIdsForMustNot[1]))
        ...

}

searchWithExclude(listOf(1, 2, ...))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this using a `terms` query instead so you can simply pass the list in argument:

```
val q = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .mustNot(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("id", foreignIdsForMustNot))
```